# Is there anyway for me to output the second highest value from multiple sheets into a cell in google sheets?

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, cell

I am making a spreadsheet with all of my Pokemon cards and on the title page I want a part that has the top five closest sets to completion but I can't figure out any of them besides the first one.

I know how to find the highest one using the MAX function but I am struggling to be able to find the ones after that do to there being too many parameters for the LARGE function.

Answer (score 0):

LARGE has only two parameters

- array/range of cells (input)
- position to return (output)

example:

```
A1     1
A2     2
A3     3
A4     4
```

---

```
=LARGE(A1:A4; 2)
```

will return "2nd largest value from range A1:A4" eg. `3`

Comment: Ya I was wondering though what I could use to fix my problem instead.